# Heroku 'couldn't detect rake tasks'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, web-deployment, rake-task

I'm trying to deploy my RoR app to Heroku but facing this error. A lot of people seem to facing a similar error but none of the solutions seem to be working.

```
    remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     LoadError: Could not open library 'aspell': aspell: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
remote:  !     Could not open library 'libaspell.so': libaspell.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
remote:  !     Could not open library 'libaspell.so.15': libaspell.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7df2cb8d9817a24b214a9c77eb08000d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/library.rb:133:in `block in ffi_lib'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7df2cb8d9817a24b214a9c77eb08000d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `map'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7df2cb8d9817a24b214a9c77eb08000d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `ffi_lib'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7df2cb8d9817a24b214a9c77eb08000d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ffi-aspell-1.1.0/lib/ffi/aspell/aspell.rb:17:in `<module:Aspell>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7df2cb8d9817a24b214a9c77eb08000d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ffi-aspell-1.1.0/lib/ffi/aspell/aspell.rb:15:in `<module:FFI>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7df2cb8d9817a24b214a9c77eb08000d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ffi-aspell-1.1.0/lib/ffi/aspell/aspell.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_7df2cb8d9817a24b214a9c77eb08000d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ffi-aspell-1.1.0/lib/ffi/aspell.rb:3:in `require_relative'
```

This is my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
java_home = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64'
ENV['JAVA_HOME'] = java_home if Dir.exist?(java_home)
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.6'

## Gems in Alphabetical Order
gem 'activerecord-session_store'
gem 'airbrake'
gem 'awesome_nested_set'
gem 'bind-it'
gem 'capistrano'
gem "capistrano-db-tasks", require: false
gem 'capistrano-rails'
gem 'coveralls', require: false
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'edavis10-ruby-web-search'
gem 'engtagger'
gem 'expertiza-authlogic', github: 'expertiza/authlogic', require: 'authlogic'
gem 'fastercsv'
gem 'ffi-aspell'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'gchartrb', require: 'google_chart'
gem "googlecharts", require: "gchart"
gem 'gdata', require: false
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-sass-rails'
gem 'jquery-datetimepicker-rails'
gem 'json', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.3'
gem 'lingua'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.8'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.2.6'
gem 'open-uri-cached'
gem 'paper_trail'
gem 'pg', group: :production
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'rails4-autocomplete'
gem 'rake'
gem 'rb-readline'
gem 'rest-client', '~> 1.8'
gem 'RedCloth'
gem 'rgl', require: 'rgl/adjacency'
gem 'rjb'
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'rwordnet', '0.1.3'
gem 'scrypt'
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.3'
gem 'seer'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'stanford-core-nlp'
gem 'superfish-rails'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'thin'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'zip-zip'
gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.0'
gem 'jquery-tablesorter'

group :development do
  gem 'daemons'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-remote'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'gherkin'
  gem 'guard-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'test-unit'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
end
```

I am able to run bundle exec rake -P without any errors.

Comment: having this same issue. about to try old version of rails i guess

Comment: @SebastianBean let me know how that works out.